# Select oldest item newer than parameter

Tags: mysql, select

A table stores data from sensors together with the corresponding timestamps. 
Having retrieved a specific entry, I'd like to get the next (newer/older) entry of that sensor.
Currently I use following query for the next newer entry:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE sensor="some_id" and timefield>"2018-1-29 11:22"
order by timefield asc
limit 1
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.
Also, the query seems to have a bad performance, though having an index `KEY HostnameTimestamp (sensor, timefield)`.

Comment: Do you use that in another program? What language are you using?

Comment: @baao it will be used in a C# program, as a parameterized query. I usually check my sql statements in MySQL Workbench before embedding them in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no better way. It should be fast enough though if you put an index on `timefield`. Also, you can do it in 1 query with subqueries if you like:

```
SELECT mytable.*, 
    (SELECT older.id 
    FROM mytable AS older 
    WHERE older.timefield < mytable.timefield 
    ORDER BY timefield DESC 
    LIMIT 1) AS older, 
    (SELECT newer.id 
    FROM mytable AS newer 
    WHERE newer. timefield > mytable.timefield
    ORDER BY timefield ASC 
    LIMIT 1) AS newer
FROM mytable
WHERE sensor="some_id;
```

Comment: Looks like a submission to an Obfuscated Sql Contest. I'll ask my colleagues if they can find out what this query is supposed to do. +1. :-)

Comment: Hah, it's simply a query with 2 extra subqueries in the selector. If you need the older and newer sensor at the same time as the selected sensor it's faster because you need less logic around it and less database connections.